# Javascripts innerHTML not working for images, but works with text?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Ok, i have a javascript function which toggles the innerhtml of a div tag when a user changes the option of a select dropdown box..

It all works fine with text, but with an image tag it stops working?

Working Example...

```
function toggle(opt) {
        var d = document.getElementById('div_tag');
        if (opt == '5') {
                d.innerHTML = 'FIVE';
        }
        else if (opt == '4') {
                d.innerHTML = 'FOUR';
        }
        etc...
}
```

Not Working Example...

```
function toggle(opt) {
        var d = document.getElementById('div_tag');
        if (opt == '5') {
                d.innerHTML = '<img src='path/img1.jpg'><img src='path/img2.jpg'>';
        }
        else if (opt == '4') {
                d.innerHTML = '<img src='path/img2.jpg'><img src='path/img1.jpg'>';
        }
        etc...
}
```

This is what i have on my select and div tags.

```
<select onchange='toggle(this.value);'>
<div id='div_tag'></div>
```

Anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here cos i am stumped.. why would one work and not the other when all that is different is one been  the other being text??

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `"` and `'` together. Can't you see that the string is being broken up when you go to specify the src? It should be throwing all kinds of errors, did you check the console or error logs for it? Should be: `'<img src="path/img2.jpg"><img src="path/img1.jpg">'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me like you forgot to escape the quotes surrounding your image paths, and its not reading your string correctly, try this

```
function toggle(opt) {
    var d = document.getElementById('div_tag');
    if (opt == '5') {
            d.innerHTML = '<img src=\'path/img1.jpg\'><img src=\'path/img2.jpg\'>';
    }
etc...
```

Comment: Of course.. d'uh haha. thanks for pointing that out, been writing so many that didnt need escaping that i forgot these did.

Comment: And you should close your tags:-)

Answer (score 1):

Do these changes, replace `'` with `"` at the beginning and end.

```
function toggle(opt) {
        var d = document.getElementById('div_tag');
        if (opt == '5') {
                d.innerHTML = "<img src='path/img1.jpg'><img src='path/img2.jpg'>";
        }
        else if (opt == '4') {
                d.innerHTML = "<img src='path/img2.jpg'><img src='path/img1.jpg'>";
        }
        etc...
}
```

You were actually using single quote instead of double quotes. `path/img1.jpg`, `path/img2.jpg` wasn't being treated part of your string earlier. That was the problem.

**UPDATE** 
For you php problem do this:

```
function toggle(opt) {
        var d = document.getElementById('div_tag');
        if (opt == '5') {
                d.innerHTML = '<img src='+'path/img1.jpg'+'><img src='+'path/img2.jpg'+'>';
        }
        else if (opt == '4') {
                d.innerHTML = '<img src='+'path/img2.jpg'+'><img src='+'path/img1.jpg'+'>';
        }
        etc...
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is not "using single quote instead of double quotes" as you said. The problem was using the same symbol for both and not escaping them. You can just as well swap them around `'<img src="path/img2.jpg"><img src="path/img1.jpg">'` because javascript uses both for strings.

Comment: Why are people in so hurry to vote down without even understanding the answer. Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: Please, vocalize it correctly. In the world of programming semantics is _everything_. What you have said is _wrong_ because it leads the OP to incorrectly understand what they have done wrong. When you give an answer, explain it thoroughly.

Comment: I think the upvoter got it right, it was only you who had problem. Any ways, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Is it that hard to want to make your answer as complete as possible? It is not about one or two people gleaning the right idea now, it is about potentially helping anyone who comes later as well. Your answer is incomplete and misleading, so I will vote accordingly.

Comment: Well a comment regarding same would have been better rather than going with vote-down. FYI, I was actually editing the answer and completing it when you downvoted. Any ways, again, it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks guys but the problem wasnt single/double it was just the escaping.