# Display images in a table column with data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on firebase cloudfirestore and I want to display image in a table column with data.

Currently I have tried to use setattribute to display the images, however when I change to dataset input, the images only shows urls. Can provide more information if needed.

add inspection
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed4bv.jpg

view inspection
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrUXR.jpg

```
uploadimage.js
var downloadU = "";
 uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downlaodURL) {
            //get your upload image url here...
            downloadU = downlaodURL;
            console.log(downlaodURL);
            document.getElementById('showImg').innerHTML = '<img src="' +  downlaodURL + '" width="50%" height="50%">';
        });

function returnPath()
{
    return downloadU;
}

addinspection.js
let photo = document.createElement('img');
    photo.textContent = doc.data()['photo'];
    photo.setAttribute('src', photo.textContent);

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('Inspection').add({
        photo : downloadU,
        HazardDiscription : form['HazardDiscription'].value,
        Location : form['Location'].value,
    }).then(() => {
        window.location.href = "addinspection.html";
    })

    form['photo'].value = '';
    form['HazardDiscription'].value = '';
    form['Location'].value = '';

viewinspection.js
function renderTable(doc){ 
dataSet.push([++count, doc.data()['photo'], doc.data()['HazardDiscription'], doc.data()['Location']);
}

db.collection('Inspection').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if(change.type == 'added'){
            renderTable(change.doc);
        } else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let li = tbody.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
            tbody.removeChild(li);
        }
    })

    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        data: dataSet
    });
})
```

Expected result should show images in the column instead of urls.

Comment: I don't see `img` html tags. Which part of the JS code suppose to display an image?

Comment: I have added the line of code, thank you to remind me on this.

Comment: Your problem may not be related to firebase because image urls are correctly fetched from the database and are shown on screen, based on screenshots you uploaded. (not as images, but as plain image url txt). There might be a problem with how you are setting `img` html tags. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266104/javascripts-innerhtml-not-working-for-images-but-works-with-text or similar questions.